# Google Reverse Geocoding for multiple addresses: problems to implement a callback function in a loop

Tags: javascript, excel, google-maps, for-loop, google-geocoder

I want to get zip codes from latitude and longitude coordinates, which are stored in an excel sheet called Test.xlsx

It looks like this:

```
             Column 1       Column 2           Column 3
Row 1        Latitude       Longitude           Result
Row 2        40.730885      -73.997383         New York City, New York 10012, USA
Row 3        ...            ...                ...
```

Since I added a loop to iterate over the rows in the excel sheet I have got problems because of the asynchronous Google Geocoder.
I think I need a callbackfunction but don't know how to integrate it into the existing code.
I already did some research on stackoverflow and the best result, which might be very useful was that one: [Google geocoding mutliple addresses in a loop with javascript, how do I know when everything is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052393/google-geocoding-mutliple-addresses-in-a-loop-with-javascript-how-do-i-know-whe)

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
    }

    function codeLatLng(){
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',',2);
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var excel_sheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet"); 
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\\Test.xlsx"); 
            excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Tabelle1");
        var i = 2;
        for(var i=2;i<=10;i++){
            var lat = excel_sheet.Range("A"+i);
            var lng = excel_sheet.Range("B"+i);     
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng':latlng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]){
                        excel_sheet.Range("C"+i) = results[1].formatted_address;
                        excel_sheet.Application.Visible = true;
                        excel_sheet.SaveAs("d:\\Test.xlsx");
                        excel_sheet.Application.Quit();
                    } else {
                        excel_sheet.Range("C"+i)="No results found";
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <input id="latlng" type="textbox" value = "40.730885,-73.997383">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onclick="codeLatLng()">
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 90%; top:60px, border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a callback function in your code.  What you need is function closure on the reverse geocode operation to associate the response with the request.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
}

function codeLatLng(latlng, excel_sheet, i){
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng':latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results && (results.length > 0 )){
                   // return the result with the type = "postal_code" (won't always be results[1]
                   for (var j=0; j<results.length; j++) {
                     for (var k=0; k<results[j].types.length; k++) {
                       if (results[j].types[k] == "postal_code") {
                         excel_sheet.Range("C"+i) = results[j].formatted_address;
                         excel_sheet.Application.Visible = true;
                         excel_sheet.SaveAs("");
                         excel_sheet.Application.Quit();
                       }
                     }
                   }
                } else {
                    excel_sheet.Range("C"+i)="No results found";
                }
            }else {
                alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });
}

function codeLatLngs(){
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',',2);
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_sheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet"); 
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(""); 
        excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Tabelle1");
    var i = 2;
    for(var i=2;i<=10;i++){
        var lat = excel_sheet.Range("A"+i);
        var lng = excel_sheet.Range("B"+i);     
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    codeLatLng(latlng, excel_sheet, i);
    }
}
```